# Wanna remove the button's borders

Tags: tkinter, uibutton, border

i just started learning Tkinter and i got a problem.
I want to remove the white border on my button. It contains just an image. (it's my first time here :) )
[borders i want to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLoZy.png)

```
rock_frame = Frame(
    fenetre,
    bg='#3366ff',
)

image_rock = Tk.PhotoImage(file='rock.png')
rock_button = ttk.Button(
    rock_frame,
    image=image_rock,
    command=rock
)
rock_button.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=134, width=107, x=40 , y=200)
```

Comment: If you use `tk.Button` you can add a `relief="flat"` option that will remove the border.

Comment: from what I have observed (this line: `Tk.PhotoImage`) it seems that you might be using python2 which is a deprecated version and you should use Python3

Comment: What have you tried? The Button widget has options for setting the border width and style, as well as options for the highlight ring.

Comment: @TheLizzard: setting the relief to "flat" doesn't remove the border, it just makes it flat. If you want to literally remove the border, set the borderwidth to zero.

Comment: @BryanOakley `relief="flat"` removes the border until the user presses on the button. I find that much better than just removing the border. It signals to the user that it's a button, while not having a border (most of the time).

Comment: @TheLizzard: terminology is important. The border is still there, it's just flat. It still adds width and height to the button.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `relief='flat'` and `borderwidth=0` to button to remove the borders.

Like this:

```py
rock_frame = Frame(
    fenetre,
    bg='#3366ff',
)

image_rock = Tk.PhotoImage(file='rock.png')
rock_button = ttk.Button(
    rock_frame,
    image=image_rock,
    relief='flat',
    borderwidth=0,
    command=rock
)
rock_button.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE, height=134, width=107, x=40 , y=200)
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a error in my code ,You need to use `tk.button` instead of `ttk.button`. Sorry once again for the mistake 