# Unable to remove or hide button border in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button, border, raspberry-pi4

I'm in the process of righting some code for a RPi 4b in python using PyCharm on my Mac.  It's going to be used as a process controller for some light mechanical work.

The display will be on a 3 1/2 inch touch screen, with a black background.  I've gotten the buttons to work properly but I cannot remove the border.  I have googled and tried various fixes including these:

[How do I remove the border of a Image Button in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72920042/how-do-i-remove-the-border-of-a-image-button-in-tkinter)

[Setting background color or bg for a button in Python Tkinter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71274233/setting-background-color-or-bg-for-a-button-in-python-tkinter-not-working)

[Wanna remove the button's borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68749215/wanna-remove-the-buttons-borders)

But nothing removes the borders.

Here's the code I'm using.

```
import tkinter as tk

# root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(bg='black')
root.geometry("480x320")
root.minsize(480, 320)
root.maxsize(480, 320)

start_png = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"start.png")
stop_png = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"stop.png")
option_png = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"options2.png")

# options button
opt_button = tk.Button(
    root,
    text='Options',
    image=option_png,
    command=lambda: root.quit()
)

# stop button
stop_button = tk.Button(
    root,
    text='Quit',
    image=stop_png,
    command=lambda: root.quit()
)

stop_button.place(x=170, y=100)

# start button
start_button = tk.Button(
    root,
    text='Start',
    image=start_png,
    command=lambda: root.quit()
)

start_button.place(x=330, y=100)


root.mainloop()
```

And here's the result.  (Please note that the first button has a black background where the other two are png with transparent backgrounds, done for tests.)

[image]

Any and all help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Update:
As Derek suggested, I tried adding `borderwidth=0,highlightthickness=0,`
to each button, it reduced the size of the border, but didn't eliminate it.

Here is the result of doing so.

[image]

Comment: You should be able to remove boundary by including `borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0` for every `Button` created.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work.  All it did was make the border slightly thinner.  See the update to the question.

Comment: Well you're halfway there. Now include `padx = 0, pady = 0` on every button.

Comment: That works.  Thanks.